# Find all possible pairs in an array c

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, int

I have a an `int array num[] = { 1,2,3,}` and I want to show all the possible 
pairs, but not the one that repeat to itself like `1 1` or `2 2` example:

```
1 2, 
1 3,
2 1,
2 3, 
3 1, 
....
```

this is what i have

```
int numb1[4] = {  1, 2,3,4,};

int i = 0;
int k = 0;

for(i ; i < 4 ; i++)
{
  for( k; k < 4; k++)
  {
     if(k != i)
     {
       printf("%d ",numb1[i]);
       printf("%d", numb1[k]);
     }
  }
}
```

my output is `12 13 14` 
I am programming in C.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine.

```
    # include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
    int numb1[4] = {  1, 2,3,4,};

    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for(i ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
      for( k=0; k < 4; k++)    // Modified
      {
         if(k != i)
         {
            printf("%d ",numb1[i]);
            printf("%d,\n", numb1[k]);   // Delimmiters
         }
      }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not initializing the loop variable `k`, which is used in the inner loop at each iteration of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

in the second for loop, you need to initialize k to 0, like this
for(k = 0; k < .....)